# Multi Level Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have a requirement from our client for crystal reports.

```
       ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC|ColumnD
Row1      A1     B1      C1       D1        
------------------------------------------------------
               ColumnE|ColumnF|ColumnG|ColumnH
Row2              A2     B2      C2       D2        
Row3              A3     B3      C3       D3  
------------------------------------------------------
                       ColumnI|ColumnJ|ColumnK|ColumnL
Row4                      A4     B4      C4       D4       
Row5                      A5     B5      C5       D5
```

It is simply three level sub report. But crystal report only support two level sub-report. I have been searching over the internet for last few hours now to find some other solution but could not find any. So I decided to put question on SO. Please guide me where to go?

Comment: try to get all data in one time, and that you can create the 3 level with the group expert, I think it's the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your data structure you have several options: You can either bring in all your information to the main report and achieve your structure by grouping correctly. You can use a s much data in the main report and get the remaining data in via a subreport, or you can use multiple subreports. I would try to achieve your goal with the first option since it's the easiest.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but we have moved towards Sql Reporting. It supports multilevel sub reporting. :)